how to get Image in database for orderClass integration test springboot
The images for the invoice are first uploaded by user via POST-image request, so that later in a POST-order request the invoiceService that auto-generates the invoice has the images within reach.(stored in db)
But now in the order integrationtest i have some strugles with the POST-image/with getting image in test-db.
in orderService:
createOrder(orderDto){
 order order = new order();
    ininvoiceService.generateInvoicePdf(order.getId());

    order.setInvoice(invoice);
    }

at invoiceService:
generateInvoicePdf{

byte[] imageTopPageBytes = imageService.getImage(imageNameTop);
            ImageData imageTopPageData = ImageDataFactory.create(imageTopPageBytes);
            Image imageTopPage = new Image(imageTopPageData);
    }

i did a try in the orderIntegrationTest:

    @SpringBootTest
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @Transactional
    class OrderIntegrationTest {
    
        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    
        @Test
        void shouldCreateCorrectOrder() throws Exception {
    
            String requestJsonProduct1 = """
                    {
                       "name": "Dorade side",
                       "category": "fish",
                       "priceInEur": "36.12",
                       "packedPerUnit": "c.a 600gr",
                       "inStock": 7,
                       "description": "fish descr",
                       "shortDescription": "fish short descr"
                    }
                    """;
    
            String requestJsonProduct2 = """
                    {
                       "name": "Vine tomatoes",
                       "category": "vegitables",
                       "priceInEur": "3.59",
                       "packedPerUnit": "1kg",
                       "inStock": 21,
                       "description": "vegi's test descr",
                       "shortDescription": "vegi's test short descr"
                    }
                    """;
    
            String requestJsonProduct3 = """
                    {
                       "name": "Basil",
                       "category": "herbs & spices",
                       "priceInEur": "2.29",
                       "packedPerUnit": "20gr",
                       "inStock": 11,
                       "description": "herbs test descr",
                       "shortDescription": "herbs test short descr"
                    }
                    """;
    
            String requestJsonCustomer = """
                    {
                        "company": "Maze",
                        "address": "10-13 GrosvenorSquare London",
                        "firstName": "Gordon",
                        "lastName": "Ramsey",
                        "dob": "1986-11-08",
                        "phoneNumber": "0644448888",
                        "emailAddress": "Gordon@cooking.nl",
                        "bankAccount": "NLINGB0021222567"
                    }
                    """;
    
            String requestJson = """
                        {
                            "customerCompany": "Maze",
                           "products": [{"productName": "Dorade side", "quantity": 3},
                                       {"productName": "Vine tomatoes", "quantity": 2},
                                       {"productName": "Basil", "quantity": 1}]
                         }
                    """;
    
    
    
            MockMultipartFile imageMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(
                    "file", 
                    "goldencarrotImagekleinste.jpg",
                    "image/jpeg",
                    "AXAXAXAX".getBytes()
            );
    
            MockMultipartFile imageMultipartFile2 = new MockMultipartFile(
                    "file", 
                    "Watermerk goldencarot factuur eindopdracht klein.jpg",
                    "image/jpeg",
                    "AXAXAXAX".getBytes()
            );
            
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/products")
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                            .content(requestJsonProduct1))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/products")
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                            .content(requestJsonProduct2))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/products")
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                            .content(requestJsonProduct3))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/customers")
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                            .content(requestJsonCustomer))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
            this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/image")
                            .file(imageMultipartFile))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/image")
                            .file(imageMultipartFile2))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()); 
            //.andReturn();
            this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/orders")
                            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                            .content(requestJson))
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
        }
    }


the error in console:    (Image format not reqognized)

    MockHttpServletResponse:
               Status = 200
        Error message = null
              Headers = [Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"77"]
         Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
                 Body = File "Watermerk goldencarot factuur eindopdracht klein.jpg" has been uploaded
        Forwarded URL = null
       Redirected URL = null
              Cookies = []
    
    jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Image format cannot be recognized.
    
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
        at nl.novi.eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot.controllers.OrderIntegrationTest.shouldCreateCorrectOrder(OrderIntegrationTest.java:161)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
    Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Image format cannot be recognized.
        at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.createImageInstance(ImageDataFactory.java:582)
        at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:82)
        at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:91)
        at nl.novi.eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot.services.InvoiceService.generateInvoicePdf(InvoiceService.java:80)
        at nl.novi.eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot.services.OrderService.createOrder(OrderService.java:97)
        at nl.novi.eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot.controllers.OrderController.createOrder(OrderController.java:38)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
        ... 77 more
    ```

ps. the image is uploaded as a multipartfile and writed compressed in db with JAVA.util.zip deflater & after fetching decompressed with JAVA.util.zip inflater.  
(All of the requests doing their work well in postman/browser, so the problem likely has to be in the testcode itself )

POST-image:

    public String uploadImage(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    
            String newImageName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            Optional<ImageDataFile> existingDataFile = imageRepos.findByName(newImageName);
            if(existingDataFile.isPresent()){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("afbeelding met deze naam bestaat al in database");
            }
            ImageDataFile imageData = new ImageDataFile();
            imageData.setName(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            imageData.setType(multipartFile.getContentType());
            imageData.setImageData(ImageUtil.compressImage(multipartFile.getBytes()));
    
            ImageDataFile savedImage = imageRepos.save(imageData);
    
            return savedImage.getName();
        }



I think this is the best way, to POST required entitys before POST-order itself with 
     mockMvc
    .perform(path:/requiredEntity) 
    .content(requiredEntityDto)
 etc etc.

& the highest coverage?
question 2: good pracice or is there a better way to do this integration testing? ;p

,coding peace 




Probably the problem was not at te testcode at all/not only,
i didn't anotate the    byte[] invoiceData     in invoiceClass as large data object.
@Lob
byte[] invoiceData;
everthing under controll! all tests passes correct.
updated testcode for image upload in mockMvc integrationtest:
Path imageTopPath = Paths.get( "C:\\Users\\m\\Downloads\\eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot\\" +       "eindopdrachtBackenSystemGoldencarrot\\src\\images\\goldencarrotImageTopPageInv.jpg");
    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(imageTopPath);
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file",
            "goldencarrotImagekleinste.jpg",
            MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
            fileContent);

  this.mockMvc
             .perform(multipart("/image")
             .file(file)
             .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
             .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
             .andExpect(status().isOk());

